# Can't write on XML file due to (TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable) using ElementTree in Python

Tags: python

I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1076, in _escape_attrib
    if "&" in text:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

when I'm trying to write an XML file with some attributes I need to edit.
Here's my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('TM_GeneralSettings.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.iter('Control'):
    numX = int(((720/1080)*float(item.attrib.get('LocationX'))))
    numY = int(((720 / 1080) * float(item.attrib.get('LocationY'))))
    numW = int(((720 / 1080) * float(item.attrib.get('SizeW'))))
    numH = int(((720 / 1080) * float(item.attrib.get('SizeH'))))
    print(numX, ':', numY, ':', numW, ':', numH)
    item.set('LocationX', numX)
    item.set('LocationY', numY)
    item.set('LocationW', numW)
    item.set('LocationH', numH)

tree.write('TM_GeneralSettings2.xml')
```

I also get this errors when I run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alessandrochiodo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    tree.write('TM_GeneralSettings2.xml')
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 772, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 937, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 930, in _serialize_xml
    v = _escape_attrib(v)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1099, in _escape_attrib
    _raise_serialization_error(text)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1053, in _raise_serialization_error
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: cannot serialize 0 (type int)
```

Can someone help me? I can't find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error for your first error.

Comment: Is it possible to display what this ```TM_GeneralSettings.xml``` is like?

Comment: You are setting some elements in `item` to numbers, but it expects them to be text. Change those to `item.set(whatever, str(thing))`